# Apify task suddenly returning 403 and 503 errors after working for months

Tags: web-scraping, apify

Not sure why this is occurring. I've been using this daily for months and it suddenly broke this morning. Its returning the following error.

CrawlerError: The page couldn't be opened (status: fail, url: https://history.com/this-day-in-history/, lastResourceError: {"errorCode":403,"errorString":"Error downloading https://history.com/this-day-in-history/ - server replied: Service Unavailable","id":1,"status":503,"statusText":"Service Unavailable","url":"https://history.com/this-day-in-history/"}, lastResourceTimeoutResponse: null)

Nothing in the code has changed, website is still up and running fine. Is there any reason why it might stop working suddenly?

Answer (score 0):

This might mean that the website now recognizes you as a bot and is blocking your requests. I would check some articles in [this docs section](https://help.apify.com/en/collections/1669748-overcoming-anti-scraping-protection). We are also working on anti-scraping guide.